# I cannot import the ArryaAdapter and ArrayList class for some reason, it was working before but I just reopened the project and now it doesn't

Tags: android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

Error:

[image: Image showing the error]

I tried rebuilding the project. When I move the cursor over it it says "Cannot  resolve symbol".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Goto File in menu -> Invalidate Cache / Restart -> Select Invalidate and Restart